# How can I add a certificate to Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, certificates

I use Arch Linux, when I want to clone a project from bitbucket with mercurial I get this error:

```
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:...:3b
    not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
searching for changes
```

- how can I fix this?
- how can I add this certificate to my shell?
- is there a pack of certificate to install? like the default certificate bundle that comes with Firefox?

Comment: Clone with... Mercurial? Git?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams update question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add certificate to fix this issue.
As described in [mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Debian.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Gentoo.2BAC8-Arch_Linux) you can add it in your configuration file /etc/mercurial/hgrc:

```
[web]
cacerts = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Also you can check the way with [fingerprints](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Host_certificate_fingerprints).

Answer (score 0):

Your code server might have an updated certificate, in which case you can just go into the `~/.hgrc` file and delete the following to force it to check for updates:

```
[hostfingerprints]
<code server> = aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
```